# I have a question about a phrase I often hear but think it is not being used correctly

Tags: phrase-meaning

Has the original meaning of "begging the question" changed?

Comment: What do you think the original meaning was?

Comment: The original meaning of "begging the question" didn't actually make any sense. — I think it may have started out as a joke translation of the Latin phrase *petitio principii*. And yes, it has also acquired another meaning.

Comment: The cited duplicate has quite a fulsome treatment of this meaning of *beg.* If that doesn't answer the question you want to ask, please [edit] this question to make it clearer and it can be re-opened. You can flag it for moderator attention when it's sufficiently different from its duplicate.

Comment: I think the original meaning has to do with a circular argument in which the conclusion is assumed to be true.